# Javascript doing nothin

Tags: javascript, html

I'm quite new in JS and while trying to make a zoom in when mousing over an image, the javascript does absolutely nothing.

I'm trying the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(function(){
        $(".image").mouseover(function()
            {
                $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
                $(this).animate({width: "500px"});
            }
        );

        $(".image").mouseout(function()
          {   
                $(this).animate({width: "250px"}, "slow");
          }
        );


   });

</script>
```

The html in which I would like to apply it is:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="title">
        <h1 class="fila1">RAINBOW BIDDING MONTHLY REPORT</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="img1" class="align">
        <img class="imagen1" SRC="URL1" />
    </div>

    <div id="img2" class="align">
        <img class="image" SRC="URL2" />
        <img class="image" SRC="URL3" />
    </div>


</div>
```

I have removed the images' URLs due to a business security issue.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix "internal" and "external" javascript within the same tag.

Replace...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
  $(function(){
```

With...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
```